# Suspension Theorem in $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, etale-cohomology, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

In algebraic topology, the suspension theorem tells us that for a topological space $X$, we have
$$\tilde{H}^n(X,F)\cong \tilde{H}^{n+k}(S^k\wedge X,F).$$
So I'm wondering if this has an analogue in the category of $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy, i.e. do we have
$$H^n_{ét}(X,F)\cong H^{n+a+b}_{ét}\left( (\mathbb{A}^1/\{0,1\})^{\wedge a}\wedge (\mathbb{G}_m)^{\wedge b}\wedge X,F\right)?$$
One thing that would make me think that this is true is the comparison theorem for étale cohomology and singular cohomology. Indeed, we have
$$\left(\mathbb{A}^1/\{0,1\}\right)(\mathbb{C})^{an}\cong S^1\cong \mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{C})^{an}$$
and thus we have
$$H^{n+a+b}_{ét}\left( (\mathbb{A}^1/\{0,1\})^{\wedge a}\wedge (\mathbb{G}_m)^{\wedge b}\wedge X,F\right)\cong H^{n+a+b}((S^1)^{\wedge(a+b)}\wedge X(\mathbb{C}),F)\cong H^{n}(X(\mathbb{C})^{an},F)\cong H^n_{ét}(X,F)$$
if we assume that $F$ is finite so that we can apply the comparision theorem. Is this true? If this argument does not work, is there another proof?

Comment: In motivic homotopy theory, we have two spheres: the classical one (as in any homotopy theory, whatever that means), and the geometric one, given by the projective line pointed at infinity, say. This makes motivic cohomology bigraded: there is the classical degree and the weight.

Comment: In étale cohomology, if you restrict to a sheaf of coefficients $F$ which is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-linear, with $n$ invertible in $\mathcal{O}_X$, the formula you seek takes the form:

$H^i_{\acute{e}t}(X,F)\cong H^{i+j}_{\acute{e}t}(X\wedge(\mathbb{G}_m)^{\wedge j},F(j))$

with $F(j)$ the $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-linear tensor product of $F$ with $\mu_n^{\otimes j}$, where $\mu_n$ is the sheaf of $n$-th roots of unity and $\mu_n^{\otimes j}$ its $j$-th tensor power.

Comment: If $X$ is defined over an algebraically closed field, we may choose a primitive $n$-th root of unity $\mu_n\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and thus get a formula which looks like the one you have in classical topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has already been satisfactorily answered in the comments. To avoid it lingering around as "unanswered," I am providing a CW answer with a reference for the observations made by Denis-Charles Cisinski.

A complete treatment of etale cohomology operations is provided in [Operations in étale and motivic cohomology](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0872.pdf), where, as the authors write in the abstract "We classify all étale cohomology operations." This includes lots of pointers to the early literature, by Epstein, Morel, Voevodsky, and others. For results of the form stated by Cisinski, see, e.g., section 7. For a result along the lines of the "suspension theorem" referenced in the OP, see page 5.